# Laravel and Sentry: How to set a custom tag in Sentry?

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, sentry

In my Laravel's `middleware` I generate a custom header value.

```
$correlationId = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();

if ($request->headers->has('Correlation-ID') === false) {
    $request->headers->set('Correlation-ID', $correlationId);
}
```

When I throw an exception I easily get it in Sentry along with my custom header.

[image]

But the power of using Sentry and Correlation Id is when you tag something, each tagged value is indexed hence it amplifies the search feature to track issues.

I've found a logic for adding tags:

```
\Sentry\configureScope(function (\Sentry\State\Scope $scope): void {
    $scope->setTag('correlation_id', app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class)->headers->get('Correlation-ID'));
});
```

The problem is that I don't know where to put it. When I add it into the same middleware it doesn't push my new `correlation_id` tag into sentry. Same when I put this code into `boot` method in `AppServiceProvider` class in a destination micro-service.

I can confirm that I get the UUID with no problems `app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class)->headers->get('Correlation-ID')` but Sentry displays only the build-in tags:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

OK, I have found the answer by myself.

The `Handler` class in `App\Exceptions` is the correct place.

```
/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return void
 */
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    if (app()->bound('sentry') && $this->shouldReport($e)) {
        app('sentry')->withScope(function (\Sentry\State\Scope $scope) use ($e): void {
            $scope->setTag('correlation_id', app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class)->headers->get('Correlation-ID'));

            app('sentry')->captureException($e);
        });
    }

    parent::report($e);
}
```

Caught issue on Sentry looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend adding tags via a middleware;

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    app('sentry')->configureScope(
        function (Scope $scope){
            $scope->setTag('my_tag_name', 'my_tag_value');
        }
    );
    return $next($request);
}
```

I've tried adding tags in `Handler.php` but without any success.